How to show nested array with ngFor?
I have an array. It contains entries like this: array[0].name and array[0].value . Thats the easy part.
I can show the first items with:
<div *ngFor="let item of fields;let i = index"> 
    i: {{ i }} {{ item.value }}
</div>

That works fine.
But i also have an array that contains an array that also might contain an array.
How should this be proper implemented in an Angular template?
This didn't work
    <div *ngFor="let itemJ of item.value;let j = index"> 
        j: {{ j }} {{ itemJ.value }}
    </div>

My Incoming Json looks like:
{
    "Name": "Person",
    "value":  {
        "adresses": [
            {
                "Name": "Adress1",
                "value": {
                    "city": {
                        "Name": "City",
                        "value": "Tokio"
                    },
                    "zip": {
                        "Name": "zip",
                        "value": "90210"
                    },
                    "street": {
                        "displayName": "Street1",
                        "value": "road to nowhere"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "Adress2",
                "value": "Perth"
            }
        ],          
        "salutation": {
         "value": "Sir"
        },
        "dob": {
            "displayName": "DateOfBirth",
            "value": "19700101"
        }           
    }

}
I only know the structure that's coming, I cant check for addresses, zip or salutation. Its kind of a Black Box.

please share the actual data object not images, what is your expected output? can you share images of the expected output?

keyvalue pipe might be useful sometimes. https://angular.dev/api/common/KeyValuePipe?tab=usage-notes

Assume you have the following data structure:


fields = [
  {
    name: 'Item 1',
    value: [
      {
        name: 'Sub-item 1.1',
        value: [
          { name: 'Sub-sub-item 1.1.1', value: 'Value 1.1.1' },
          { name: 'Sub-sub-item 1.1.2', value: 'Value 1.1.2' },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'Sub-item 1.2',
        value: 'Value 1.2',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Item 2',
    value: 'Value 2',
  },
];



Template Implementation
<div *ngFor="let item of fields; let i = index">
  <div>
    i: {{ i }} {{ item.name }} - {{ item.value }}
  </div>
  <!-- Check if value is an array -->
  <div *ngIf="item.value && item.value.length" style="margin-left: 20px;">
    <div *ngFor="let subItem of item.value; let j = index">
      <div>
        j: {{ j }} {{ subItem.name }} - {{ subItem.value }}
      </div>
      <!-- Check if value is an array -->
      <div *ngIf="subItem.value && subItem.value.length" style="margin-left: 20px;">
        <div *ngFor="let subSubItem of subItem.value; let k = index">
          <div>
            k: {{ k }} {{ subSubItem.name }} - {{ subSubItem.value }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

